Problemas instalar REACT
Al momento de ejecutar este comando
npx create-react-app .
no me deja porque busca un intalador de react 19, ya verifique al iniciar mi aplicacion que node sea una version mayor, tengo la version 22
Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: pj2@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@19.0.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^19.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm error node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm error   @testing-library/react@"^13.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\Joseh\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-24T20_06_41_960Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Joseh\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-24T20_06_41_960Z-debug-0.log
`npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^13.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 web-vitals@^2.1.0` failed

me salen estos errores, me podrian apoyar a como solucionarlo

intente instalarlo con Vite, una herramienta que puede hacer más intuitiva la instalación de la misma y evite errores a la hora de la descarga de los paquetes requeridos.
Usa este comando para iniciar el proyecto:
npm create vite@latest

Después escoges la librería o framework que desees usar podrás instalar tus módulos necesarios.
Si persiste el error, puede que el problema se relacione con Internet inestable o debe de actualizar a una versión más reciente a npm:
npm install -g npm@latest

